# How to link image to product after reverse image search

Tags: tensorflow, flask, deep-learning, e-commerce, vision

Building a reverse image search with Deep learning-based feature extraction following [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-deep-learning/9781492034858/ch04.html) tutorial. The folder structure for my data is like this:

```
├── Data
│   ├── shirt
│   ├── red_shirt
│   └── black_shirt
```

After doing an image search I find result against **queried image** is like :

[image]

Now I have **names** of similar images but how to **link** them to that product page. Any dynamic way?

I want to add a link like the below:

[image: What I want!!]

**N.B.**: My backend is based on Flask.